# How is NASA's mod II Stirling engine so powerful yet so small?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature

Is it because of the temperature difference? I just don't understand how it can propel a car.

Here's the link to the engine:
http://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19880002196_1988002196.pdf

Comment: Are you talking about this: https://tec.grc.nasa.gov/rps/advanced-stirling-convertor/ ? If so, please add the link to your question, or otherwise add the right one.

Comment: No I wasn't but thanks for letting me know. I added the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stirling engines work best when the working gas is as light as possible and under high pressure, so as to maximize its thermal conductivity.
As your link says, that engine uses Hydrogen, the lightest gas, at pressures in the range of 1450 psi, or about 100 atmospheres.
That's comparable to the pressure in scuba tanks.

Engineering problems with leak-proof seals are very difficult with Hydrogen at high pressures.