# How does this Stirling engine work?

Tags: thermodynamics

I'm looking at [this](http://books.google.ca/books?id=RN4_jLbVO3YC&pg=PA50&dq=Stirling+auto+engine+a+lot+of+progress,+but+Spirit&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=true) Stirling engine, which I believe is a variation of an alpha type. It was developed by Nasa back in the 1980's. The thing is, I can't figure out how the hydrogen cycles  through the pistons. Could someone help me? This is another [link](http://www.ohio.edu/mechanical/stirling/engines/engines.html) that might help you understand what it looks like if you scroll down about 3 quarters. There are several pictures on this page. I've tried making sense of it but I don't understand how the heated hydrogen cycles.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/91853/how-is-nasas-mod-ii-stirling-engine-so-powerful-yet-so-small

Comment: I'm trying to find how the hydrogen circulates though.